# I just updated the software of my S4 Active, and now my mobile data doesn't work

Tags: mobile-data

I've tried turning my data and wifi on and off, played with airplane mode, restarted my phone a few times, and left the battery out for nearly 15 minutes, but my mobile data still isn't working after this software update. Any tips on how to get it running again? I'm not good with tech, and I'm thinking about just going into a tech guy before work tomorrow and having them look at it, but I'd rather save the trouble if I can.

Comment: Which update? Which carrier? First thing I would try is back up all your pictures, apps, texts, then perform a factory reset. You can easily backup your apps and text messages by using the `adb backup` command from a computer.

Comment: Give us some details: 1) Can you see that mobile data is turned on in quick settings or Settings app? 2) If yes, do you see an icon, such as E, H, H+ or something on the same lines on the signal indicator in status bar?

Answer (score 0):

You can try these solutions. But first, take backup of your device.

1. Try factory reset. It is possible that previous config files/residual files maybe causing the conflicts.
2. Flash the latest radio image or just flash latest image of ROM.